# Sharing of vector for AES encryption and decryption

Tags: cryptography, aes, salt, encryption-symmetric, secret-key

We are using AES encryption to encrypt and decrypt data that is sent between browser and the server. AES encryption needs a secret key,which is hard coded and known by the client and the server.

Apart from the shared secret key, AES encryption also needs an initialisation vector( IV), which is unique and generated every time when a new request is sent either from the client or the server.

Is it ok for sharing this uniquely generated vector in every request in the http header between browser and server ? Are there any security risks in doing so?

Comment: The IV does is not meant to be a secret and should usually just be prepended to the encrypted data by the sender and stripped off by the receiver to use in their cipher instance.

Comment: Agree. IV is not secret. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: AES does not need an IV, it's the mode of operation that requires the IV. There is a lot of problems getting an authenticated transport protocol to work, if you use CBC encryption you may be vulnerable to padding oracle attacks, for instance, mostly nullifying any encryption used. Use TLS.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. We are already using TLS. The requirement is to provide end to end encryption of payload considering the data sensitivity ( even our own network staff should not be able to sniff data)